# wxWidgets C++ wxDirDialog shows empty window and pauses the program

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

my C++ code

```
void MyFrame::sub_load_directory(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
    // Create a new wxDirDialog dialog
    wxDirDialog* dirDialog = new wxDirDialog(this);

    // Display the dialog and transfer the contents to
    // the wxTextCtrl on the main frame if the user
    // doesn't cancel
    if (dirDialog->ShowModal() == wxID_OK)     \\ Program pauses here
    {
        txtOutputFile->SetValue(dirDialog->GetPath());
    }

    dirDialog->Destroy();
}
```

Im using `wxWidgets 3.1.5` on `Windows 11`, ive copied the examples and if just pauses the program . `WxFileDialog` works , so `wxDirDialog` should also work

Comment: please do not cross-post the same thing in 2 different places (at keast at the same time). In regards to your problem - I made a post on the wx forum - please check it out.

Comment: Can you give a link to the post

Comment: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=49060